# Livewire detected in Chrome but cannot use tools

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 6.20 along with Livewire 1.3.9, and I receive this message when I try to debug a component. I'm not sure what setting it is that is preventing the tools from appearing - my config files all say debug/development mode. Any ideas?

[image: Livewire Detected]

Comment: Same message on MacOS 12.6 / Laravel 9, Livewire 2 using Laravel Sail.. in both Firefox and Chrome. Also with the official Chrome addon.

Comment: Check your `APP_DEBUG` and `APP_ENV` values.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to restart Chrome, that worked for me.